# Angular 2 pass click to app.component from route-outlet

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2 and creating an application

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar (sideMenuToggleClicked)="handleSideMenuToggle()"></app-navbar>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-2 test-border" *ngIf="sideBarToggle">
            <h1>
                {{sideBarToggle }}
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-10 test-border" [ngClass]="sideBarToggle?'col-10':'col-12'">
            <app-alert *ngIf="showAlert"></app-alert>
            <router-outlet (showAlert)="handleShowAlert($event)"></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**register.component.ts**

```
@Output() showAlert = new EventEmitter();
onSubmit(){
 this.registerService.getValues(this.registrationForm.value).then((result:any)=>{
        console.log(result)
       }).catch((error:any)=>{
         this.showAlert.emit({type:'error', message:error});
       });

      }
```

As you can see i was successful in capturing the click in app-navbar which is loaded as component.

Now i am trying to create a common alert notification and when i try it with

```
<router-outlet (showAlert)="handleShowAlert($event)"></router-outlet>
```

I was not able to capture the EventEmitter Click.

Question is how can transfer the emit from register.component.html to app.component.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662456/angular-2-output-from-router-outlet

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11618

Comment: I got it working with above two links. The answer is from stackoverflow and the provider we need to define in app.module.ts not in components

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like you are trying, it will try to look `showAlert` on `RouterOutlet` directive which it will not find.

you need to check how [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Hope this helps!!