# Use @Output with <router-outlet> of "angular 4.0"

Tags: angular, angular-components

Use a selector to succeed.

```
<app-child1 (onVoted)="onVoted($event)"></app-child1>
```

But using a router will fail

```
<router-outlet  (onVoted)="onVoted($event)"></router-outlet>
```

I want to receive a value from a component displayed on the "router-outlet".

Please tell me what method I have.

app：https://toparent.herokuapp.com/ 
src:https://github.com/kuniatsu/routerQuestion

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<a href="c1">child1</a>
<router-outlet  (onVoted)="onVoted($event)"></router-outlet><!--fail-->
<hr />
<app-child1 (onVoted)="onVoted($event)"></app-child1><!--success-->
```

Comment: you cannot create `@Output` variable to angular packages. What you mean by this line **"I want to receive a value from a component displayed on the router."**

Comment: Use a service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: >>Mr.Aravind   「you cannot create @Output variable to angular packages.」Why??? https://toparent.herokuapp.com/ 　Press the second displayed button.title is changed.@Output is working normally.But only selectors.I hope you will be able to provide the information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 output from router-outlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662456/angular-2-output-from-router-outlet)

Answer (score 4):

You can define an @Output event emitter in the component being rendered at router-outlet.
define router outlet as follows.

```
*.html
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

In your component you can do as so.

```
onActivate(elementRef) {
    elementRef.<the @Output eventEmitter>.subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
    });
}
```

This way you can send the events to the component which is rendering router-outlet. This works because @Output event emitters are event streams and you can subscribe to those events.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: Should I unsubscribe manually inside one of the Angular hooks? If I should, then in what hook? Thank you.