# Having trouble using @Ouput decorator to communicate with parent in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

I know that there are questions relating this topic and I took a look at the docs but I couldn't understand how to use outputs.

I have a child component with this @Output

```
//here I define the Ouput on the child component
@Output() turvo: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

//here I emit the event on the child component
ngOnInit() {
  this.turvo.emit(false);
}
```

The parent component

```
//here I listen to the emitted event on the parent
<div (turvo)="atribuirTurvoDoFilho($event)"></div>

//here is the function that should be executed on the parent.
public atribuirTurvoDoFilho(data) {
  console.log("I will never execute :(");
  this.turvo = data;
}
```

I got no errors but no communication occurs.

Comment: The event handler must be set in the child component tag: `<my-child-component (turvo)="..." ></my-child-component>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between component in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501577/how-to-communicate-between-component-in-angular)

Comment: I am using router-outlet, is there any issues?

Comment: The event handler must be set on the component tag of the component that emits it.

Comment: @DiegoAlves - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37662456/1009922) should answer your question about handling events with a router outlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a working solution, please share your full child component.

For now, I can see, that you try to run your output on the div element - which is a html tag, not a angular component.

If you define an output, it will be working only for that component where is defined.