# Angular EventEmitter from component to app.component

Tags: angular, angular5, eventemitter

I would like to bind an event emitter from a child to a parent component, but the parent component is the 'app.component'so i assume that the relationship between the two is not declared but implicit.
 
in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076701/594765) answer , i see how to add an event emitter to a child that has been explicitly declared as such, in his parent:

```
<child (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></child>
```

But in my app, the child component (lets call id: child), is not declared in that way, but its declared in the `app.module` as route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '**',      component:  Child}
];
```

This component basically represents a splash page to the site, and is also used as a redirect in a guard in case full authentication is not provided. 
What i would like to do, is to add an event emitter to `child` that notifies `app.module` of a change.
I have already implemented, in `child` an `EventEmitter` with the `@Output()` decorator, and i have also implemented the method that will be invoked in `app.module` but i just cant find a place where to register this binding within the two components.
Since all components are children of `app.component` should not `app.component` provide a way to register for incoming input from its children, without the need of declaring them explicitly as children first?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37662485/1009922).

Comment: Check out my answer. its a different approach and I think can be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, from my understanding you'll have to explicitly bind the `app.component` and `child.component` to actually make the Event emitter work.

From your scenario, you can also consider using `Subject` to achieve the same. You dont have to explicitly define for every `child.component`, rather you can simply Subscribe and listen to any changes that are happening.

[I have created one link to help two sibling & parent components talk](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-observable-1lcns3?file=app/hello.component.ts). You can do the same for Several child and one parent

**app.component.html**

```
<br />
Enter a name:
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myTextVal">
<button (click)="sendTextValue()">Click Me to emit to Hello Component</button>
<hello></hello>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myTextVal: string;

  constructor(private appService: AppService){}

  sendTextValue(){
    this.appService.passValue(this.myTextVal);
  }
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  public stringSubject = new Subject<string>();

  passValue(data) {
    //passing the data as the next observable
    this.stringSubject.next(data);
  }

}
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor(private appService: AppService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.stringSubject.subscribe(
      data => 
      {
        console.log('next subscribed value: ' + data);
        this.name = data;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @AngryCoder : It expired somehow. Please check now. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A parent-child component relation is given when your 'child' component is called in your 'parents' html template. So if your component is in your app.components html template then it's a child of app.component and you can pass data between the two using `EventEmitters`.

If there is another component between those two, then you'd have to use a service to share data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add

```
<child (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></child>
```

In your parent component template i.e. app.component in your case, in order to listen to the "notifyParent" event. Move the method implementation from app.module into app.component.ts file and it will work.

Comment: hi, thank you, but i was actually asking if there is an alternative to that, but i appreciate your effort in replying

Comment: You can use Subjects by declaring it in a shared service, and push a $event to this subject every time there's an event emitted. And subscribe to this subject in your app.component