# can eventEmitter work on router-outlet?

Tags: angular, eventemitter, router-outlet

I have  in my parent component, where I want to detect the emitted event.

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})   
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit { 

    @Input() public state: String = 'CLOSED';

    @Output() public stateChanged: EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();

    this.stateChanged.emit(this.state);
```

}

parent.component.html

```
<router-outlet (stateChanged)="onStateChange($event)"><router-outlet>
```

parent.component.ts

```
onStateChange(event){
    console.log(event);
}
```

This doesn't work for me!

The compiled HTML code looks like:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<child-component>
    // all child component code
<child-component>
```

Is there any way to push `(stateChanged)="onStateChange($event)"` in `<child-component>` element?

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Use a service. Routes keep your components decoupled from the rendering hierarchy, don't try to change that

Comment: Could you please provide an example, if possible?

Comment: `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root') export default class {change = new Subject(); triggerChange() { this.change.next();}`

Answer (score 10):

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` considered to be a `placeholder` with the purpose of adding `routed components`. It does not have support to any kind of bindings.

But there is an update to `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` with an event that allows getting added component : [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37662485/6426617)

```
<router-outlet (activate)="componentAdded($event)" (deactivate)="componentRemoved($event)"></router-outlet>
```

This helps to communicate with getters, setters and methods through `componentAdded()`

The preferred way is to use a shared service check these links to create shared services

1) [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

2) [Create shared service angular](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

3) [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989983/6426617) [Example2](https://embed.plnkr.co/8kmQcSDlDhCSKbACbWSx/)

Comment: there ARE bindings available on <router-outlet> now. for example you can event bind to `(activate)="doAThing($event)"` which gives you the event anytime you the router loads a new component. `doAThing(e) {console.log(e.constructor.name)}` will give you the name of the component

Comment: Thanks ! then i can just access any output i want from the `$event`, it is the actual component. event easier than using emitter

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot have event Emitter on  **`router-outlet`**.

I would suggest you to have your own componnet with input property and use the even on that

`<list [list]="list" (onStateChanged)="stateChanged($event)"></list>`

Comment: Thanks, @Sajeetharan, for your answer. But I have updated my question. Can you please look at that?