# Child to parent communication in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have header and body in my Angular components.

Have a notification count in the header and would like to update the count whenever the count gets changed by user in the body.

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const AppRountes: Routes = [{
   component: LayoutComponent,
   children: [
    {
     path: 'notification',
     loadChildrent: './notification/notification.module#NotificationModule'
    }
   ]
  }]
```

I have a NotificationComponent for notification.

The notification icon and the count is there in the LayoutComponent.

Here, I would like to notify from NotificationComponent to LayoutComponent.

I am able to communicate from LayoutComponent to NotificationComponent using @ViewChild, but not sure how to communicate from child to parent.

Comment: Best method would be using a shared service between the components.

Comment: This is not an option for now as it needs lots of changes in the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would use an `EventEmitter`plus `@Output`, since you're using the router you cannot really do this. I think you can find an answer here though: [Angular 2 output from router-outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662456/angular-2-output-from-router-outlet)